# How to I put an "X" to clear the search box in my Flutter TextField Widget?

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield

Below code provides the TextField for search, however, I want a "X" to clear on the right hand side so the user can clear the search without having to backspace.

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                //Placeholder potential X for clearing search
                /*suffix: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => TODO),*/
                hintText: 'Search by name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white)),
            onChanged: (string) {
              setState(() {
                filterAssets = assets
                    .where((test) => (test.name
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(string.toLowerCase())))
                    .toList();
              });
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a `textController`..

And `onPressed` you can clear it..

```dart
TextField(
            controller: textController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                //Placeholder potential X for clearing search
                suffix: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => textController.clear()),
                hintText: 'Search by name',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white)),
            onChanged: (string) {
              setState(() {
                filterAssets = assets
                    .where((test) => (test.name
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(string.toLowerCase())))
                    .toList();
              });
            },
          ),
```

Hope it solves your issue..